# Salesforce Admin and Development

Tags: lightning, community, developer, admin, encoding

I’ve worked on SF in my previous job for couple of years managing cases. Furthermore,have worked as a Subject Matter Expert. Also, was a part of migration from Classic to Lightning. In a nutshell, have a good knowledge of driving SF (Classic and Lightning)as a end user.

Now, I gradually want to work my way up to become a Salesforce Developer. I do not have a coding background though.

Is it a good idea? If yes, how long it might take to get through SF admin and PD-1 certificate?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For the admin certification, it sounds like you might be nearly ready. Make sure you go through the Admin Beginner trailhead modules first.

For the PD1, you might want to start off with lower level programming first. Take your time to learn the basics of computer logic before you start on Apex.

I'd suggest maybe starting off on an Arduino or Raspberry Pi first to get a feel for computer logic, and Java because it is very similar to Apex (and it's easy to learn). You can then move on to JavaScript, you'll want that for all the UI stuff you'll be doing in Salesforce once you get far enough along.

This background will help you write more efficient algorithms, which is important for Apex. For reference, I learned dozens of languages before Salesforce, and it's been incredibly helpful over the last two decades.

Do not rush to get to PD1 if you're not already familiar with programming. I'd guess that three to six months of preparatory work will enable you to not just get a PD1, but also a real job that will earn real money. You'll also want to take the trailhead modules first; they're required.

That said, programming isn't for everyone. Some people just can't grasp computer logic efficiently. Pay attention to your own strengths and weaknesses. You might find a rewarding career in admin, or maybe Marketig Cloud might be more your thing, etc.

Finally, there if a lot of open source Salesforce software out there. You might consider finding some projects and contributing. That's a great way to learn how to code.